# django AttributeError, type object 'object' has no attribute python 3

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

got an error when post the data

```
AttributeError at /system/create/
type object 'object' has no attribute 'EmpInstallment'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/system/create/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'object' has no attribute 'EmpInstallment'
Exception Location: /Users/wakanda/pyproject/payroll/system/views.py in form_valid, line 117
Python Executable:  /Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/wakanda/pyproject/payroll',
 '/Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.0.1-py3.6.egg',
 '/Users/wakanda/py-virtualenv/payroll3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configparser-3.5.0-py3.6.egg']
```

**model.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    nik = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("system:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class EmpLoan(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='emploan')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp.name

class EmpInstallment(models.Model):
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    loan = models.ForeignKey(EmpLoan, related_name='empinstallment')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.loan.emp.name
```

**view.py**

```
class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('spl', 'status')
    model = models.Employee

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        try:
            pinjaman = models.EmpLoan.objects.get(emp_id=1, status=0)
            cicilans = models.EmpInstallment.objects.filter(loan_id=pinjaman.id).values_list('id', flat=True)
            totalcicilan = 0
            for i in cicilans:
                cicilan = models.EmpInstallment.objects.get(id=i).nominal
                totalcicilan = totalcicilan + cicilan

            sisapinjaman = pinjaman.nominal - totalcicilan

            if ( 12 - cicilans.count()) != 0:
                cicilansekarang = sisapinjaman / ( 12 - cicilans.count())
            else:
                cicilansekarang = 0

            #potongan cicilan
            hasil = round(cicilansekarang)

            if hasil != 0:
                joe = models.EmpInstallment.objects.create(loan=pinjaman, nominal=hasil)
                object.EmpInstallment.add(joe)
            else:
                statatus_pinjaman = models.EmpLoan.objects.get(emp_id=1, status=0)
                statatus_pinjaman.status = 1
                statatus_pinjaman.save()

        except models.EmpLoan.DoesNotExist:
            hasil = 0

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

when I click submit on my form, its showing error but checked on my database it's submitted.

what wrong with my code?...

especially on

```
joe = models.EmpInstallment.objects.create(loan=pinjaman, nominal=hasil)
object.EmpInstallment.add(joe)
```

please explain because I am a slow learner and super noob on Django & OOP.

Answer (score 5):

`object` is Python's buitin. I suppose you need to use `self object`:

```
self.object.EmpInstallment.add(joe)
```

Comment: can I use `self.object` also when using 2 models or more?... I mean when I click submit on my form, 1 data going to model 1, and another submitted to second or more model.

Comment: now `'Employee' object has no attribute 'EmpInstallment'` on same line. since my `class EmployeeCreateView(CreateView):` add data to 2 models. `Employee` and `EmpInstallment` and they not related. `Employee -> EmpLoan -> EmpInstallment`

Comment: @DickyRaambo `self.object` is instance of `Employee` class. So it doen't have EmpInstallment atribute. Probably you want to add manytoone relation between `Employee` and `EmpInstallment`? In this case you should add `employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='EmpInstallment'). After `makemigrations` and `migrate` your code should work

Comment: if my scheme like this `Employee -> EmpLoan -> EmpInstallment` how do it?... so `EmpInstallment` have foreign to `EmpLoan` and `EmpLoan` foreign to `Employee`

Comment: @DickyRaambo `eploan=self.object.emploan.first()` and then `eploan.empinstallment.add(joe)`. Now first emploan related to employee will contain new object. But it's not very good solution. Instead of it i recommend you to rewrite your scheme as i suggested.

Comment: can you suggest new scheme?... what scheme should I do.

Comment: @DickyRaambo you can add direct relation between employee and `empinstallment`. Just add to `EmpInstallment` model `Employee` foreign key: `employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='EmpInstallment')`. After this changes your view should work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, If you do this:

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
```

You need to call the save method when you're done, like:

```
self.object.EmpInstallment.add(joe)
self.object.save()
```

But, I would advice you change the name from `self.object` to something else because it could confuse you and might conflict with python. Even though it is an object, you could give it a better name like `new_emp_installment`.

Lastly, this line:

```
return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Should be:

```
return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in your this line.

```
object.EmpInstallment.add(joe)
```

when you use `object` then it is considered as python's built-in `object`.

You should use like

```
self.object.field_name.add(joe)
```

that will be

```
self.object.emp.add(joe)
```

then it will add mentioned model.